# C# Populate DataGrid having ComboBox, CheckBox and TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, combobox, populate

I've got a DataGrid with 6 columns:
ComboBox;ComboBox;CheckBox;CheckBox;CheckBox;TextBox

I'm trying to populate this DataGrid with values I'm keeping in List of GridLine objects

```
    public class GridLine
    {
     public string sColumnA { get; set; }
     public bool bError { get; set; }
     public string sColumnB { get; set; }
     public bool bNullableB { get; set; }
     public bool bCollateB { get; set; }
     public bool bStaticB { get; set; }
     public string sStaticB { get; set; }
     (...)
    }
```

I've wrote a function that is setting DataGrid last line params and add new line but it is not working correctly - I'm getting only ComboBoxes on last line properly set, anything else:

```
        private void AddLine(GridLine gl)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cellMs = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cellOra = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellNull = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2];
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellColl = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3];
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellStat = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4];
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cellStatText = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[5];

        cellMs.Value = gl.sColumnA;
        cellOra.Value = gl.sColumnB;
        cellNull.Selected = gl.bNullableB;
        cellColl.Selected = gl.bCollateB;
        cellStat.Selected = gl.bStaticB;
        cellStatText.Value = gl.sStaticB;

        this.Rows.Add();
    }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a binding list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx of items (GridLine) you want to add to datagridview. Then assign datagrid's property DataSource with that list.

Before you do that you will need to add columns in a designer to datagridview.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx